# Execute SSIS package from Java calling Catalog procedures

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, ssis

so what Im trying to do is call a stored procedure `usp_Something` that contains something like this

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]
    @folder_name = @f_name,
    @project_name = @pro_name,
    @package_name = @pack_name,
    @execution_id = @exec_id output

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @exec_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value=1

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @exec_id
--SET @output_execution_id = @exec_id
```

In Java im doing a connection with JDBC Driver using a SQL Server authentication trying to call `usp_Something` procedure. But I get an error

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server
>   Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows
>   Authentication.

Now, I know you need to use Windows authentication to run packages, but is there any workaround? I've been told not to use Windows authentication so I need a way for this to work using SQL Server authentication

Comment: I would guess it is not possible. However this might be something that is better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my project was to use integratedSecurity:

jdbc:sqlserver://${db.server};databaseName=${db.name};instanceName=${db.instance};integratedSecurity=true;

Connection to db will be done using the same user running your java application. In my case, I run my spring-boot application as a domain user, which is also configured to connect to SQLServer and execute Stored Procedures.